# Отступы с помощью margin

Tags: java, css, javafx, margin

Подскажите, как в javaFX установить размер текстового поля с помощью css?
Можно ли чтобы размер открываемой картинки как то зависел от размеров экрана?
И вообще, как сделать так, чтобы на мониторах разных размеров визуально все выглядело одинаково. Слышала про margin'ы, но ничего подходящего не нашла. Посоветуйте что то пожалуйста про это!

Answer (score 0):

1. размер текстового поля задается уймой способов, например, через свойства width, height.
2. можно. задайте размер картинки в единицах, зависящих от размера экрана (а точнее, клиентской части окна браузера) - `vw` и `vh`.
3. нужно как-то определить размер экрана. если вы имеете в виду в пикселах - то задавайте через `vw` и `vh`. если в сантиметрах - найдите способ запросить у устройства его размеры, например, тут (одними css не обойтись): [find screen dimensions in inches not pixels using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606069/find-screen-dimensions-in-inches-not-pixels-using-javascript) и повычисляйте...
4. А что маргины? Они тут не при чем...